# how to place a link on the first post only using a plugin

Tags: plugins, the-content

i want to add a link to the first post of every WP blog that i have. For example this simple function adds the link to every post.

```
    function add_link($link){

    $link .= '<a href="http://site.com">Link</a>';
return $link;
    }
    add_filter('the_content','add_link');
```

so basically instead of the link showing below each post, I want it to show only at the bottom of the first post only.

thanks.

Comment: Still not solved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove the filter when it is called the first time:

```
function add_link($link)
{
    // this will guarantee the filter will not be called again.
    remove_filter( current_filter(), __FUNCTION__ );
    return $link . '<a href="http://site.com">Link</a>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Trivial with some basic logic

Add before your function:

```
$added = false;
```

Then check e.g.:

```
    if(!$added ){
        $added = true;
        $link .= '<a href="http://site.com">Link</a>';
    }
```

Comment: I think you mean `if (!$added)`. Also it's not really clear where this $added variable is scoped. @toscho's answer is much cleaner.